# Импорт Go пакетов из GOPATH/src

Tags: golang

Можно ли импортировать в проект, находящийся за пределами GOPATH (в любом произвольном месте), пакеты из GOPATH/src?

Проект с каким-то go.mod.

Пакеты в GOPATH/src естественно не скомпилированные. Кроме того они нигде не опубликованы, то есть к ним нет доступа, как к удалённым пакетам.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Можно импортировать исходники пакетов из любого места. Это можно сделать, отредактировав `go.mod`

Для примера предположим, у вас `go.mod` выглядит вот так:

```
module example.com/mymodule

go 1.16

require (
    example.com/othermodule v1.2.3
    example.com/thismodule v2.3.4
    example.com/thatmodule v3.4.5
)
```

Чтобы указать `go` в какой папке искать исходники модуля, нужно добавить в `go.mod` инструкцию `replace`:

```
module example.com/mymodule

go 1.16

require (
    example.com/othermodule v1.2.3
    example.com/thismodule v2.3.4
    example.com/thatmodule v3.4.5
)

replace example.com/thatmodule => /path/to/thatmodule
```

Comment: => /path/to/thatmodule - путь должен быть абсолютным?

Comment: Может быть относительным. В этом случае за базу берется папка, в которой находится go.mod

Comment: Уже проверил и абсолютный, и относительный. Абсолютный путь - не универсальный вариант. Относительный - от файла из проекта go.mod, а нужно относительно GOPATH. Кроме того в обоих вариантах требует наличия go.mod в импортируемом пакете, которого там быть не должно, так как этот пакет находится в пределах GOPATH.

Comment: Зачем вы привязываете себя к GOPATH? `go.mod` специально сделан для того, чтобы отвязаться от этой странной конструкции. ИМХО, лучше перевести все компоненты на модули, чем держать костыль GOPATH. Я ещё два года назад всё смигрировал в модули, с тех пор никаких проблем.

Comment: Привычка после питона. Если не привязываться к GOPATH, тогда нужен другой универсальный способ достучаться до пакетов, импортируемых разными проектами, расположенными чёрт знает где. Способ универсальный для разных систем, с точкой отсчёта не от проекта, или системы, а от какой-либо переменной среды.